# coefficient from logistic regression to write function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I just completed logistic regression. The data can be downloaded from below link:
[pleas click this link to download the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DNLuOQUgk8v4184wtnFDuaEmUs3s5ZfK)

Below is the code to logistic regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import pandas as pd
scaler = StandardScaler()

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataX = data.drop('outcome',axis =1).values.astype(float)
X     = scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
dataY = data[['outcome']]
Y = dataY.values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X,Y,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 33)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Predict the probability of the testing samples to belong to 0 or 1 class
predicted_probs = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
print(predicted_probs[0:3])
print(lr.coef_)
```

i can print the coefficient of logistic regression and i can compute the probability of an event to occur 1 or 0.

When I write a python function using those coefficients and compute the probability to occur 1. I am not getting answer as compared using this :**lr.predict_proba(X_test)**

the function i wrote is as follow:

```
def xG(bodyPart,shotQuality,defPressure,numDefPlayers,numAttPlayers,shotdist,angle,chanceRating,type):
coeff = [0.09786083,2.30523761, -0.05875112,0.07905136, 
         -0.1663424 ,-0.73930942,-0.10385882,0.98845481,0.13175622]

return  (coeff[0]*bodyPart+ coeff[1]*shotQuality+coeff[2]*defPressure+coeff[3]*numDefPlayers+coeff[4]*numAttPlayers+coeff[5]*shotdist+ coeff[6]*angle+coeff[7]*chanceRating+coeff[8]*type)
```

I got the weird answer. I knew sth wrong in the function calculation.

May i seek your advice as I am new to machine learning and  statistics.

Comment: your xG function does not use the formula for logistic regression, hence the weird results. You are treating a logistic regression as a linear regression in xG. The formula for logistic regression is 1/(1+e**(insert what you return in xG here))

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I hv lasso coe and intercept, how can write a function using coe and intercept to predict y value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the `intercept_` in your `xG`. You can retrieve it from `lr.intercept_` and it should be summed in the final formula:

```
return 1/(1+e**(-(intercept + coeff[0]*bodyPart+ coeff[1]*shotQuality+coeff[2]*defPressure+coeff[3]*numDefPlayers+coeff[4]*numAttPlayers+coeff[5]*shotdist+ coeff[6]*angle+coeff[7]*chanceRating+coeff[8]*type))
```

Comment: Hi Marco, Thanks for the advice. Right now, the some of the values that i am getting are  negative. The answer are supposed to lies between 0 and 1. if i add intercept to that equation,i think there will still be negative value. is that something to do with transformation from sigmoid function? Thanks

Comment: Yes! If I remember well you need to take the value of your `return` and pass it to the sigmoid function: `1/(1+e^(-x))`.